# Why can I not rename my Excel VBA Class Module?

Tags: excel, vba, class

Renaming an Excel Class Module should be a simple task (i.e. in the Properties Window, select the Name field and change it). I have successfully changed it before, and now I am trying to rename it again, but it gives me this "Can't perform requested operation" error every time:

[image]

I have no other modules with the same name that might conflict. What is preventing me from completing this operation?

Comment: What are you trying to rename it _to_?  Are you sure it's a legal name?

Comment: "ctgxTimingInfo" to "ctgxTiming". I've never seen anything like this before. It's baffling me because it should be so straight forward.

Comment: Are you in break mode?  Or something else already exists with the same name?

Comment: That _is_ a legal name.  To rule out "ctgxTiming" being used elsewhere, try changing to some other random name.  If that fails,  I'd suspect the file is corrupted

Comment: @TimWilliams I just tried cycling power (i.e. I closed it and opened it again) and it let me change the name with no issue. Looks like that might have been the culprit. Maybe I was in break mode and didn't realize it?

Comment: Typically I only see that message in Break mode (and after a little testing the class in question needs to be "in use" when the break is entered).  I just tested and a name conflict gives me a different message "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"

Comment: @TimWilliams I think you got the answer. That's the error it throws when you're in break mode. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this message if you try to rename a class module while the project is in Break mode and the class in "in use"